# Cracking MD5($p.$s)

Tags: password-cracking

I have a salt and a password for an application that is using MD5($password + $salt) and I'm looking to crack it. I believe this to be the same format that joomla uses. I'm having trouble figuring out the file format to pass to Jack the Ripper.

I've tried

```
username:password:salt
username:password$salt
username:password#salt
```

But I get

```
./john --format=MD5 --subformat=joomla raw.txt 
No password hashes loaded
```

The password is simple enough that it appears in word lists but I'd like to make a point about brute force times.